# Pasar uno o varios tax_id a odoo 9 (a su api nativa)

Tags: php, api, odoo

Actualmente tengo esto:

```
$line_array_product = array(
    'order_id' => new xmlrpcval($erp_order_id, "int"),
    'type' => new xmlrpcval('Product', "string"),
    'product_id' => new xmlrpcval($erp_product_id, "int"),
    'price_unit' => new xmlrpcval($total_price, "string"),
    'product_uom_qty' => new xmlrpcval($details['product_quantity'], "string"),
    'name' => new xmlrpcval(str_replace('+', ' ', urlencode($details['product_name'])), "string"),
    'discount' => new xmlrpcval($reduction_rate_tax_excl, "string"),
    'tax_id' => new xmlrpcval($erp_tax_id, "string"), ## <-- Problema aqui
    'ecommerce_channel' => new xmlrpcval('prestashop', "string"),
);
```

Quiero poder pasarle a Odoo 9 los impuestos pero por algún motivo odoo no me está recibiendo el dato (API nativa de odoo 9).

Se que el tax_id puede recibir varios ids pero no tengo claro como..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Había que darle formato de como pide odoo así:

```
$tax_id = new xmlrpcval(
    array(
        new xmlrpcval(
            array(
                new xmlrpcval(6, "int"),
                new xmlrpcval(0, "int"),
                new xmlrpcval(
            array(
                new xmlrpcval($erp_tax_id, "int"),
            ), "array")
        ), "array")
    ), "array");


$line_array_product = array(
    'order_id' => new xmlrpcval($erp_order_id, "int"),
    'type' => new xmlrpcval('Product', "string"),
    'product_id' => new xmlrpcval($erp_product_id, "int"),
    'price_unit' => new xmlrpcval($total_price, "string"),
    'product_uom_qty' => new xmlrpcval($details['product_quantity'], "string"),
    'name' => new xmlrpcval(str_replace('+', ' ', urlencode($details['product_name'])), "string"),
    'discount' => new xmlrpcval($reduction_rate_tax_excl, "string"),
    'tax_id' => new xmlrpcval($tax_id, "string"),
    'ecommerce_channel' => new xmlrpcval('prestashop', "string"),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si no me equivoco el campo `tax_id` de la tabla `order_line_id` es del tipo `many2many`, asi que prueba haciendolo de esta manera:

Si tienes un valor:

```
'tax_id' = [(0,0,{'id_tax_en_tabla_m2m': 1})]
```

Si tienes varios valores:

```
'tax_id' = [(0,0,{'id_tax_en_tabla_m2m': 1}),(0,0,{'id_tax_en_tabla_m2m':2}),...]
```

Quisiera ser mas exacto pero hace mucho que no uso **Odoo** y no tengo ejemplos a la mano.

Aqui esta lo indicado por su documentacion:

> For a **many2many** field, a list of tuples is expected. Here is the list of tuple that are accepted, with the corresponding semantics:
>
> (0, 0, { values }) link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary
>
> (1, ID, { values }) update the linked record with id = ID (write values on it)
>
> (2, ID) remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)
>
> (3, ID) cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target object itself)
>
> (4, ID) link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)
>
> (5) unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records)
>
> (6, 0, [IDs]) replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo malo es que actualmente se está haciendo con xmlrpcval y si no lo trabajo todo igual me salta un error 500 :( Pero ha sido muy útil !! Investigo más